# Xamarin - Microcharts Graphics and Label

Tags: c#, xamarin, charts, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I'm using this plugin to Xamarin Forms:
 https://github.com/aloisdeniel/Microcharts

Microcharts is great and it's the best I've seen to show charts so far...
BUT... When using it, there is a way to specify the location to show the label? 
For example, if I use a RadialGauge and my label value or text is big, it goes over the chart graphic.

right now I'm using this code (inside a custom render to the ChartView) to show the label:

```
var entry = new List<Microcharts.Entry>();
var dataEntry = new Microcharts.Entry(ValorAtingido);

this.Chart = new Microcharts.RadialGaugeChart();

string myValue = Math.Round(this.ValorAtingido, 1).ToString();
string objective = Math.Round(this.ValorMeta, 1).ToString();

dataEntry.ValueLabel = myValue + " de " + objective + " (" + this.Percent + "%)";
dataEntry.Label = "Novo Teste";
this.Chart.LabelTextSize = 20;
```

This code results in this:
[image]

So, is there a way to choose if I want the label in the top, bottom, left, right of the graphic? Or something similar to that that can help me?

Comment: You may get the answer faster if you will ask it directly on the github project's page.

Comment: Yep, I posted there too

Comment: Placement of label elements is hardcoded in `DrawCaptionElements` and is based upon the margin. Fork the project and create your public/virtual  `DrawCaptionElements` so you can override it in subclasses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, there isn't a simple way to do that...
the developers are thinking about add this feature in the next releases, as you can see in these links:
 - https://github.com/aloisdeniel/Microcharts/issues/31
 - https://github.com/aloisdeniel/Microcharts/issues/33
 - https://github.com/aloisdeniel/Microcharts/issues/28

And, as you can see in the comments in your question, another user gave a good tip about how the label is created, you can use it to make an override and draw your own labels.

> Placement of label elements is hardcoded in DrawCaptionElements and is
>   based upon the margin. Fork the project and create your public/virtual
>   DrawCaptionElements so you can override it in subclasses... –
>   SushiHangover

Comment: am pretty sure *Rai Calvs* and *Calvin Numes* are the same person :) pretty strange that Rai is only answering for calvin and the question of Rai only answered by calvin .. and Rai giving good comments to Calvin and vice versa, a lot of coincidence don't you think :) both account created at almost the same time and the photo is also similar :)

Comment: i might be wrong but if it's the case simply pay attention as i know many people got banned for doing such things (multiple accounts to boost reputation) ... the system here can easily detect this behavior

Comment: We used to work together  i don't enter here frequently, but when I do, i help friends with questions i know and give them a boost :D

Comment: he told me that he lost many rep days ago cause I liked his things with too many frequency

Comment: How to make MicroChart as interactive. i.e. I want to enable the legends to be clickable

Comment: @Ashaar open a new question here in SO, comments are not the place to ask new questions. See [ask]